# Bootstrap vs Foundation for responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

What are the pros and cons of Bootstrap and Foundation when focusing on responsiveness of the web page with dynamic contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Bootstrap and Foundation tackle the issue of responsive design the same way. It's mostly up to your preference which one you use because they have become so similar in nature.

[This article](https://medium.com/frontend-and-beyond/8b3812c7007c) should help you decide which one is better for your project.